# Reverse engineer the VBA code you need to produce graphs in a slide

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am looking for a way to kind of re-engineer the VBA code I need to create a certain visual in PowerPoint.

For example purposes let's say, I want to create code to create this:

[image]

Right now I have wrote the following VBA code that allows you highlight the shapes used in the powerpoint:

```
Sub ListAllShapes()

Dim curSlide As Slide
Dim curShape As Shape

For Each curSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
    Debug.Print curSlide.SlideNumber
    For Each curShape In curSlide.Shapes


                MsgBox curShape.Name


    Next curShape
Next curSlide
End Sub
```

If I run this with my example I get the following output:

Autoshape 7

However when I then lookup the Shape.name here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.msoautoshapetype I see that Autoshpape 7 is msoShapeIsoscelesTriangle. If I then insert the following code:

```
Sub InsertShape()

Set myDocument = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
myDocument.Shapes.AddShape Type:=msoShapeIsoscelesTriangle, _
    Left:=50, Top:=50, Width:=100, Height:=200


End Sub
```

I get a different graph, any thoughts on where I am going wrong?

[image]

Comment: Maybe look at:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.shaperange.autoshapetype

Comment: You might try recording a macro in Word or Excel and see what that gives you. They all use the same Microsoft Engine for Shapes objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The autoshape **Name** is not the autoshape **Type**. They're 2 different properties. Here's a macro to add all the shapes to a slide. Then look up the number on this page to get the VBA AutoshapeType name: [MsoAutoShapeType enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.msoautoshapetype)

```
Sub MakeShapes()
    Dim T As Long, L As Long
    Dim oShape As Shape, oText As Shape

    T = 0
    L = 0
    x = 1
    For y = 1 To 15
        For Z = 1 To 26
            On Error GoTo NoShape
            Set oShape = ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes.AddShape(Type:=x, Left:=L, Top:=T, Width:=30, Height:=30)
            On Error GoTo -1
            Set oText = ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes.AddTextbox(Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, Left:=L, Top:=T + 36, Width:=36, Height:=18)
            With oText.TextFrame2.TextRange
                .Text = oShape.AutoShapeType
                .Font.Size = 10
            End With
            Set oShape = Nothing
            Set oText = Nothing
            L = L + 36
NoShape:
            x = x + 1
            If x = 184 Then Exit Sub
        Next Z
        L = 0
        T = T + 71
    Next y
End Sub
```